Ethercat-grant error with binary installed package
For context: Our package, adi_tmc_coe, which is already released on the ROS index, uses ethercat-grant to run without root privilege.
ethercat-grant is included in both CMakelist and package.xml of our package. When installing the package from source (dependencies were installed via rosdep install command), everything works fine. However, we encounter error from ethercat-grant when installing our package via binary (dependencies were automatically installed when installing our package via sudo apt install).

We also checked other packages in ROS index that use ethercat-grant, specifically rokubimini_ethercat. We tested both source and binary installations, and, like our package, we encountered the same error during the binary install.

Our analysis suggests that ethercat-grant is copying the executable (in this case, the shared object of the package) and modifying its permissions. However, since it is installed as a binary, the shared object is located in /opt/ros/noetic/ which requires root permissions thus the error we encountered.
Has anyone experienced the same issue? What suggestions do you have? Thank you!

You don't need root privileges to run anything in /opt/ros. That would be needed for editing files there. The errors you see are library lookup errors. So either the libraries are not correctly installed to /opt/ros/noetic/lib, or the ethercat-grant does something wrong to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You can try running ethercat-grant ldd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/adi_tmc_coe/tmc_coe_ros_node to see where your system is looking for the libraries. Try running it with and without ethercat-grant. If you get some that are not found, you'll have to figure out how ethercat-grant changes the library path.

Hi @MartinPecka, thank you for your comment. We used ethercat_grant as recommended, by including it in out launch file using launch-prefix command. It is expected that ethercat_grant will not show up when checking the shared object of the node.
Update: I checked the RPATH/RUNPATH of the copied executable. I noticed that packages that are binary installed does not have RPATH or RUNPATH as they rely on LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and this is what causes the error on ethercat_grant side.
